# Algorithm for Estimating Number of Unique Monthly Visitors

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, statistics

Is there a way to estimate the number of unique monthly visitors to a site based on a limited sample of one week of data? I have information about when a given user visited the site. This isn't as simple as just multiplying the number of unique visitors the first week by 4, due to [the hotel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_analytics#The_hotel_problem). If 10 people visit your site the first week and the same people are the only visitors to your site the second, third, and fourth week, the total number of monthly unique visitors to your site is only 10.

I know you can use HLL to estimate the number of unique visitors to a site in O(1) space. I'm wondering if there's a similar approach to estimate how many unique visitors there will be after a month, preferably that also works in O(1) space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into this for a bit, I came across [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224763717_Estimating_the_Prediction_Function_and_the_Number_of_Unseen_Species_in_Sampling_with_Replacement) which provides a solution. The paper gives an approach to estimating the number of new species that will be observed given an initial sampling period. It models observing a given species as a Poisson distribution. It gives the following estimator for the number of new species that will be discovered:

$$
\hat{\Psi}(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{k_{m a x}} N_{k} e^{-k}-\sum_{k=1}^{k_{m a x}} N_{k} e^{-k(1+t)}
$$

where $N_{k}$ is the number of species that were observed $k$ times and $t$ is the length of the second sample relative to the initial sample.

Answer (score -1):

Not without making assumptions.  You can't tell the difference between a site with a $N$ users who visit once a week (on a random day of the week), vs a site with $4N$ users who visit once a month (on a random day of the month).

Comment: Of course. Presumably there is some approach that factors in how often a new user shows up to come up with better estimate. I'm looking for any approach that could take a sample of information of the users (not necessarily just the number of unique visitors over the course of a week) and estimate the number of unique visitors for a month.

Comment: @malisper, I've answered the question as stated.  Doing what you suggest would require extra assumptions or extra information not stated in the question.  We can only answer the question that was stated; we can't read your mind about what other assumptions you might have in mind or be willing to make.  Also, it is helpful to tell us in the question what you already know about the problem so we don't waste your time or our time telling you something you already know.

Comment: Ok. I edited the question to try to make it clearer. Does it make sense? I think some of the confusion was around "I have one week of data". It seems you interpreted that as I know the unique number of visitors after one week, when I meant I have one week of data on how visited my site and when.

Comment: @malisper, there was no confusion.  I understand what you meant from the start.  My answer continues to apply.  Having all the data for a single week doesn't resolve the issue I have pointed out.

Comment: Aren't there statistical approaches you can apply? The [German tank problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem) seems to be a similar problem. For the German tank problem you can't tell what N actually is, but there are still approaches to estimate it. I would think the same thing applies here. I don't know what N actually is, but there seems like there should be ways to approximate it.

Comment: @malisper, no, and my answer explains why.  There is no statistical technique that can distinguish the two cases listed in my answer because the distribution of what you can observe is absolutely identical in every way.

Comment: I don't see how that follows. If I had 10 people visit the first day, then the same 10 visit the second day, and so on, that would make me think N is closer to 10. If each of 10 people visited once at a random time throughout the week, my estimate would be closer to 40. 

Using this intuition I think a possible approach would be something like using the sample to estimate how often a random person visits the site and then use that to estimate the total number of people who will visit the site over the course of a month.

Comment: A graphical interpretation of this intuition is if you plot the number of distinct users with the size of the sample the number of distinct users would grow sublinearly. Presumably there is some way to approximate the shape of the curve and figure out what it will look like over the course of a month.

Comment: @malisper, I hope someone else is able to help you.  I'm not able to assist further and am not interested in continuing the conversation.  If you are interested in working it out on your own, I suggest you work through the scenario I presented in my answer (rather than some other scenario you have selected).  If you have $N$ people who each visit once per week, then what do you expect to see in the logs?  If you have $4N$ people who each visit once per month, then what do you expect to see in the logs?